# Giving parameters to arrow function in Haskell

Tags: xml, haskell, xml-parsing, monads, arrows

I have an XML file with some data. This file has a description of columns and the data itself. I can read column names, but I can't read data because I do not understand how to give this row names to a function which will return the data.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document>
<Header>
<Project code="SOME PROJECT" label="PROJECT LABEL"></Project>
<Datatable name="LOG" label="Visits"></Datatable>
<Columns>
    <column name="study" label="Study" ordinal="1" type="TEXT"></column>
    <column name="site" label="Site" ordinal="2" type="INTEGER"></column>
    <column name="number" label="Subject" ordinal="3" type="INTEGER"></column>
    <column name="visit" label="Visit number" ordinal="4" type="CHARACTER VARYING(20)">     
 </column>
 <column name="vdate" label="Visit date (dd/mm/yyyy)." ordinal="5" type="CHARACTER   VARYING(10)"></column>
</Columns>
</Header>

<table xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

   <row>
   <study>Some study</study>
   <site>1</site>
   <number>1</number>
   <visit>1</visit>
   <vdate>28/12/2010</vdate>
   </row>

   <row>
   <study>Some study</study>
   <site>1</site>
   <number>1</number>
   <visit>2</visit>
   <vdate>03/03/2011</vdate>
   </row>

   <row>
   <study>Some study</study>
   <site>1</site>
   <number>1</number>
   <visit>3</visit>
   <vdate>09/06/2011</vdate>
   </row>

   </table>
   </Document>
```

Sample code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs

parseXML :: String -> IOStateArrow s b XmlTree
parseXML file = readDocument [ withValidate yes
                             , withRemoveWS yes
                             ] file

atTag :: ArrowXml a => String -> a (NTree XNode) XmlTree
atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)

text :: ArrowXml cat => cat (NTree XNode) String
text = getChildren >>> getText

getRowsData :: ArrowXml cat => cat (NTree XNode) [String]
getRowsData = atTag "table" >>>
    proc l ->  do
        row <- atTag "row" -< l

        study <- text <<< atTag "study" -< row
        site <- text <<< atTag "site" -< row
        returnA -< [study,site]

readTable :: ArrowXml t => t (NTree XNode) [[String]]
readTable =
    proc l -> do
        rows <- listA getRowsData -< l

        returnA -< rows

main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- runX ( parseXML "log.xml" >>> readTable )
    print res
```

The problem for me is in `getRowsData`. In the sample code I gave column names implicitly, but I want it read from a list, apply in arrow function and return rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import Control.Arrow
```

### Combining lists of Arrows

I believe what you're looking for is a way of combining multiple arrows on the same input to list their output:

```
list :: Arrow a => [a b c] -> a b [c]
list [] = returnA >>^ const []
list (a:as) = (a &&& list as) >>^ uncurry (:)
```

`(a &&& list as)` returns a pair of the head and the tail, then we post-apply `>>^` the pure function `uncurry (:) :: (x,[x]) -> [x]` to recombine them.

Let's test it. Here are some things to play with IO arrows. A monad is an arrow, but you have to wrap it into its Kleisli category. `runKleisli` unwraps it again so you can run it, but takes me too long to type, so I've used an infix version `>$>` to feed it the input:

```
ask :: Kleisli IO String String
ask = Kleisli $ \xs -> putStrLn xs >> getLine

(>$>) = runKleisli
```

So now it's easier to interact:

```
*Main> ask >$> "Hello?"
Hello?
Hello!
"Hello!"
```

and `list` works fine:

```
*Main> list [ask,ask] >$> "say something!"
say something!
OK
say something!
What do you want me to say?
["OK","What do you want me to say?"]
```

### From [String] to arrow returning [String]

But you want to turn a list of Strings into an arrow that produces lists of Strings.

```
appList :: Arrow a => (s -> a b c) -> [s] -> a b [c]
appList f xs = list (map f xs)
```

We can test that with a variant on the ask test:

```
askRespond xs = Kleisli $ \thx -> do
                       putStrLn xs 
                       ans <- getLine
                       putStrLn thx
                       return ans
```

So we can see `appList` is working the way you want, by making an arrow out of each String, and running each, combining the answers into a string again:

```
*Main> appList askRespond ["What's your name?","What's your favourite colour?","Would you like some cheese?"]  >$> "Thanks."
What's your name?
Andrew
Thanks.
What's your favourite colour?
Green
Thanks.
Would you like some cheese?
Yes - could I have gruyere?
Thanks.
["Andrew","Green","Yes - could I have gruyere?"]
```

### Grabbing multiple tag contents

Now let's apply that to your problem.

First let's make a shorthand to make an arrow out of a string:

```
textAtTag xs = text <<< atTag xs
```

Then let's use `appList`:

```
getRowsData = atTag "table" 
          >>> atTag "row"
          >>> appList textAtTag ["study","site"]
```

I haven't tested that last one - please check!

Comment: Thanks a lot for such good explanation! Your approach works fine! I will study all you have written in details. Thanks!